# How to taper multiple meshes (a radio mast)

Tags: objects, edit-mode

I want to create a model of a tapered radio mast which is constructed from multiple meshes (as per attached). The base is 1 metres square and I want to taper the entire object so that the top is (approximately) 0.5 metres square. I have tried converting the meshes to a single mesh and then in edit mode select the outside 'points' of each 'leg' and use Scale but can't get that to work.
I know there is a method but just can't work it out. The model is in a very rough stage at the moment but I will tidy that up before the taper.
After watching a video tutorial I think I need to use geometry nodes however the I have no idea how to use it and the author of the video doesn't explain enough for me to work it out.
Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

[added later] Just noticed the real life mast appears not to have sloped sides but to be made up from a number of sections each one smaller than the one beneath as in this image (the best I could find online)
[image]

Comment: try using the Lattice modifier https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUcPXLI9ATk

Comment: Thanks. After rewatching I got the 'hang of it' and was able to taper my tower. I quickly discovered that I needed to set the W (resolution) to only 2 to make the entire height taper (instead of only part of it). This Blender tool is great and so powerful.

Answer (score 1):

For a straight-sided taper, you can use *Simple Deform > Taper*, but as things are, that will scale the struts as well as the tower, if they are already part of the geometry.

Just out of interest, you don't need 'multiple meshes' for this object. You can avoid scaling the thickness of the components along with the whole object.  The tower can be made from a Z-scaled cube with some loop-cuts, an Empty, and some modifiers...

[image]

1. Scaled, divided cube and an Empty, bottom-center, rotated in Z by 45°
2. *Vertex Proximity* modifier, with the Empty as target (only if you want the example's curved taper, otherwise *Simple Deform > Taper* will be easier)
3. Displace modifier, along normals, by the vertex group modified in step 2
4. *Triangulate* modifier (Fixed pattern)
5. Unfortunately no triangulate pattern is naturally the one in your mast, so *Mirror*, in the the Empty's X and Y, with 'Bisect'
6. *Wire Frame* modifier.

The result even gives you good topology at the joints:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes I was wondering about scaling of thickness of the components.   I am trying to create a model based on a real radio mast but now I see that the real life mast does not have tapered sides but is made up of a number of straight sided sections each of a slightly smaller sections. It was difficult to judge from online images taken from quite a distance 
(see image I just added to question. Regardless of anything though, the object is for a flight simulator airport and will only ever be viewed from probably equivalent of around 50 feet (16 metres).

Comment: And it would seem the mast is triangular not square which adds an issue I have not yet attempted but may make a simple square mast as who is going zoom in and notice AND its only a simulation.

Comment: @JohnArnold The nice thing about modelling procedurally is that the [switch to triangular](https://imgur.com/a/dqNq1vC) is just a few steps.. Same with varying strut-length... etc.. etc.